# Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app while deploying in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

i am deploying my django+react app on heroku but its raising this error every time

> Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

i have tried every thing remove cache delete package-lock.json update the node version according to .env file and other packages , app working fine in local but not deploying on server.i have this error so far at every time please help me to resolve i have also follow the heroku documentation to resolve this issue but not worked for me.

Comment: why does this related to `django` tag?

Comment: then you should mention your project structure because i don't see where you describing about django in this

Comment: i have added the project structure pic

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: okay i got it.i have removed the pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved my issue by little bit changing into my package.json file
**before:**

> scripts": {
> "start": "cd frontenduser && npm install && webpack-dev-server --env.NODE_ENV development",
> "build": "cd frontenduser && npm install && webpack --env.NODE_ENV production",
> "test": "jest --watch"   },

**after:**

> scripts": {
> "start": "cd frontenduser && npm install ",
> "build": "cd frontenduser && npm install",
> "test": "jest --watch"   },